# Flex popup from outside resource weather warnings

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am using the USGS service of NHSS NOAA weather warnings in an application.  I have the service displaying in my map using
http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/nhss_weat/MapServer
The service shows that identify is supported.
The question is how do I get a popup from this service with the warning type and other info?
If I try to use the same service I get no popup, If I point it at my own server I get a popup with no information.
I have also tried using the [atom described here](http://products.weather.gov/PDD/cap1.1final.pdf) but not sure of the exact usage in this context.

Any help would be appreciated.